# Implementing pagination in codeigniter, can't get count

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, pagination, mysql-num-rows

I am having difficulties implementing the codeigniter pagination class. I have created my model, view and controller for getting my news articles and data is echoed in the view successfully.

My problem is that when I attempt to implement pagination it seems like I am unable to get the correct count of fields in my database. Can somebody show me what I have done wrong?

The pagination links display perfectly, but the content echoed does not appear to be limited. How can I count the rows of the query?

*Required classes for the pagination are autoloaded*

**Model:**

```
class News_model extends CI_model {


    function get_allNews()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');

                    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = array(
             'category' => $row->category,
            'title' => strip_tags($row->title),
            'intro' => strip_tags($row->intro),
            'content' => truncate(strip_tags( $row->content),200),
              'tags' => $row->tags

        );
    }

    return $data;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
      // load pagination class
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/news/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('news')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = '5';
  $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

$viewdata['allnews'] = $this->News_model->get_allNews($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
```

**View**

```
  <?php if (isset($allnews)): foreach ($allnews as $an): ?>
               <?php echo heading($an['title'], 2); ?>
                <?php echo $an['content']; ?>
            <?php endforeach;
        else: ?>
            <h2>Unable to load data.</h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you're passing parameters to your get_allNews method, but your method doesn't make use of those parameters:

```
$viewdata['allnews'] = $this->News_model->get_allNews($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
```

So you are getting all records, and expecting the limited result set. You need to change the beginning of your get_allNews method like this:

```
class News_model extends CI_model {

// make use of the parameters (with defaults)
function get_allNews($limit = 10, $offset = 0) 
{
    // add the limit method in the chain with the given parameters
    $query = $this->db->limit($limit, $offset)->get('news'); 
    // ... rest of method below
```